# How can I change My monitor Imageing postion to left when i set low resolution?

Tags: windows-10, display

**ITs not a multiple-monitor related question.**

I have a 3440 * 1440 monitor. Accidently the right side of the panel is broken. So I was trying to project the screen to the left side in 2550 * 1440 resolution. But when scale it as aspect ratio and change the resolution, the projection remains in the center  I was trying to move it to the left side of the monitor to make the monitor usable for a couple of days.
[Broken monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npXCz.jpg)
[Change TO 2k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/029ht.png)

Comment: This question gets asked so frequently - but always worded differently making it hard to search. the answer is invariably, "No, this cannot be done"

Comment: I'm reasonably certain I've seen a similar question here in the past year or two asking how to change where the monitor renders a sub-native resolution image on the panel. I have not yet found the question though. I believe the answer was that it depends on the monitor hardware, and either it will support rendering in alternate locations or it will not.